# PHP Zip not working correctly

Tags: php

I have this code:

```
$nomeZip = str_replace(".result", ".result.tar.gz", $pathAndFileName);              
$a = new PharData($nomeZip);                  
$a->addFile($pathAndFileName);                    
$a->compress(Phar::GZ);                    
unlink($nomeZip);
```

Where:

```
$pathAndFileName = C:/wamp/www/prove/WORKSPACE/7d5e0799/SelectResult1.result
```

in my folder I obtain 2 files:

1. `SelectResult1.result.tar.gz`
2. `SelectResult1.tar.gz`

The first file have the same dimension of original file (bad)

The second file dimension is ok, but I want only one file with this name: 
`SelectResult1.result.tar.gz` and effectly zipped

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/phardata.compress.php), `compress` adds the `.gz` extension by default. So just don't add `.gz` to your `$nomeZip`.

Also, you'll need to destroy the `PharData` object before unlinking the `.tar`:

```
unset($a);
unlink($nomeZip);
```

Comment: your solution is OK. Though I obtain SelectResult1.tar.gz and not SelectResult1.result.tar.gz

Comment: @mydb Interesting, it seems that `$a->compress(Phar::GZ)` removes everything after the first dot in the filename and then appends `.tar.gz`. A workaround would be to change the filename after the Phar operation has completed. Or to use `$a->compress(Phar::GZ, '.result.tar.gz');`.